# Linux: same device mounted on differences mount points

Tags: linux, mount

I have a system with following `/etc/mtab`:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/foobar /etc/somefile ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/foobar /var/lib/somedir ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/foobar /mnt/foobar ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/foobar /mnt/foobar/somedir ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

i.e. the same device mounted in different mount points. What's more:

1. Those directories have different contents (this precludes `mount --bind` case)
2. Some of those mount points are regular files

Strangely enough, `df -h` shows only one of those mount points:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/foobar    2.8G   70M  2.6G   3% /mnt/foobar
```

How is this possible? What's going on?

Comment: The most authoritative place you can view your mounts is in `/proc/self/mountinfo` I would suggest you look there for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/etc/mtab is showing the result of using bind mounts, is my guess. You can bind mount any directory, and I suspect you are seeing the result of that.

```
$ mkdir test/ /tmp/test
$ sudo mount --bind test/ /tmp/test
$ cat /proc/mounts
<..snip...>
/dev/root /tmp/test ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

This question provides a more in-depth explanation/example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128471/determine-what-device-a-directory-is-located-on

`df -h` is not showing these because bind mounts are 'dummy' filesystems, and `df` requires `-a` to show those.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. What was new to me, "One can also remount a single file (on a single file). It's also possible to use the bind mount to create a mountpoint from a regular directory" (man mount)